# How to detect if first day of the week is Saturday, Sunday, or Monday?

Tags: php, date

What is a dependancy free solution for my PHP application to detect the first day of the week for the running php process? Example:

- Saturday (Middle-Eastern week calendar)
- Sunday (Western week calendar)
- Monday (ISO-8601 week calender).

I have tried this:

```
$first_day_of_week = date('l', strtotime('This week'));
```

I expected the code to return Sunday for american users and Monday for european. But it always returns Monday (an ISO-8601 week calendar).

Comment: If you want to get the Client time based on Server time then use a Universal Time Constant, which can be passed to JavaScript `$passToNewDate = time()*1000;`. Since PHP does seconds and JavaScript takes milliseconds `*1000`. I would AJAX that to `const dt = new Date(dateAJAXresult); console.log(dt.toString())`.

Comment: Appreciate the effort. This is distributed code that needs to identify the week type on the local machine. So not for the browser client, but the machine itself.

Comment: `date_default_timezone_set('America/Vancouver')` sets the php.ini timezone for the `date` function. For multiple timezones consider [DateTime::setTimezone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php#usernotes).

Comment: @StackSlave Yes but I tried setting date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles'); But it still outputs Monday.

Comment: Start of week is always `ISO-8601` in PHP date functions. You'll have to add or subtract.

Comment: @StackSlave And how does the application know wether it should add or subtract in an end user's environment?

Answer (score 0):

Athough not a dependancy free solution. Here is detecting week type using the PHP extension Intl.

```
if (extension_loaded('intl')) {
  switch (IntlCalendar::createInstance()->getFirstDayOfWeek()) {
    case 1: $first_day_of_week = 'Sunday'; break; // Western
    case 2: $first_day_of_week = 'Monday'; break; // ISO-8601
    case 7: $first_day_of_week = 'Saturday'; break; // Middle Eastern
  }
} else {
  trigger_error('PHP is missing the Intl extension', E_USER_WARNING);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first day of the week returned by

```
$no = IntlCalendar::createInstance()->getFirstDayOfWeek();
```

depends on your php.ini. You get the default value with locale_get_default().
IntlCalendar::createInstance() accepts a locale as the 2nd parameter, which then delivers different results for the first day of the week.

```
foreach(['en_AE','en_US','en_GB'] as $locale){
  $no = IntlCalendar::createInstance(null,$locale)->getFirstDayOfWeek();
  $weekDayName = date('l', strtotime('Saturday +'.$no.' days'));
  echo $locale.' : '.$weekDayName.'<br>';
}
```

Output:

```
en_AE : Saturday
en_US : Sunday
en_GB : Monday
```

Regardless of this, the following applies for date and DateTime:

> Start of week is always ISO-8601 in PHP date functions.

(as already noted in the comment)

Comment: Yes, same method as the previous answer. But not a dependancy free solution. Not all end-users have the intl extension loaded. Any other ways?

Comment: The intl extension is standard these days.
PHP cannot see where the server is and which local calendar is used there. All of this information must ultimately be set in the server configuration.